# Dynamically Updating Text outside Matplotlib (Python)

Tags: python, matplotlib, text

Morning All,

I'm stuck with an issue in Matplotlib whereby I am unable to clear all features outside of the plots.

**Context**

I have two axes, ax1 is a scatterplot, while ax2 is a 3D Bar chart plot (fig. 1).

There is a function (`drillhole_summary`) that runs whenever a point (or drill hole) is selected in ax1. This `drillhole_summary()` then displays the names of all drill holes selected outside of both ax1 and ax2.

```py
            def drillhole_summary():

                dh_textstr = ('Drill Holes Selected: ' + str(drillholes_selected))
                plt.gcf().text(0.10, 0.40, dh_textstr, fontsize=14)
```

**The Issue**

The issue is that previous instance of the names of drill holes isn't update, it is just being overwritten.

[image: Figure 1]
*Figure 1* Click to enlarge

**Attempted Solutions**

I have attempted to write over the text with the same string but in a white coloured font. This creates a ghostly image of text. Other attempts result in both ax1 and ax2 getting wiped clean, or the programme becomes blank.

Any feedback will be appreciated!

Comment: you can adjust the visibility of your text the same way you adjust the visibility of your plot. either with ``set_visibility='visible'`` or ``set_visibility='hidden'`` or ``visible=True`` or ``visible=False``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution that I could come up with was to make use the ax1 legend and dynamically update it with each click on ax1 (see image).

[image]